# Box shadow won't "none" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to have a div that shows content and have a box shadow once clicked. Then I want to click on the div again to hide the content and box shadow. All is working great except for the box shadow that won't be hidden once its been clicked on in my second function that sets it to none. Why will this not work?

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 top" id="time">
<div class="clickme" id="clickme" onclick="clickme(); 
return false;">
<p>Click here for the time and date!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function clickme(){
document.getElementById("clickme").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("time").style.boxShadow = "inset 6em 6em 6em #3B3130";
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "<h2 onclick='revert();''>It is " + theTime + " and the date is " + theDate + "</h2>";
}

function revert(){
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("clickme").style.display = 'inline';
document.getElementById("time").style.boxShadow = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Btw. stuff like that is usually done using classes, not by applying styles directly.

Comment: Perhaps caused by the double `'` in this section? `onclick='revert();''>` BTW, if you actually want to unset an inline CSS value, you can just set it to a blank string.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, fixed it but still no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you "destroy" the div `#clickme` when you modify the inner HTML of its parent.

See it working just fine when I moved the elements a bit:

```js
function clickme() {
  var theTime = 'some time';
  var theDate = 'some date';
  document.getElementById("clickme").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("time").style.boxShadow = "inset 6em 6em 6em #3B3130";
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "<h2 onclick='revert();''>It is " + theTime + " and the date is " + theDate + "</h2>";
}

function revert() {
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("clickme").style.display = 'inline';
  document.getElementById("time").style.boxShadow = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 top" id="time"></div>
<div class="clickme" id="clickme" onclick="clickme(); 
return false;">
  <p>Click here for the time and date!</p>
</div>
```

And don't forget - stuff like that is usually done using classes, not by applying styles directly.

Answer (score 1):

@Shoms already identified the error in your code but I just want to give you a little more direction. I find it useful to move logic into the CSS wherever possible and just use javascript to add and remove classes. The advantage here is that you can easily fiddle with the CSS to change the look in different states without changing the javascript. Here is a possible solution.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
box.onclick = function() {
  if (box.className.indexOf("clicked") == -1) {
    box.className = "clicked";
  } else {
    box.className = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#box #time {
  display: none;
}
#box.clicked {
  box-shadow: 1em black;
}
#box.clicked #firstMessage {
  display: none;
}
#box.clicked #time {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p id="firstMessage">Click here for the time and date!</p>
  <p id="time">Time to get a watch!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this! I am going to study and play around with it because I do want to understand as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("time").style.boxShadow = null;
```